# import csv with a column with several numbers with 0 before them

Tags: psql

I have a csv file (tab separated) that looks like:

```
    code  description
    ----  ----------------
    0011  it is a car
    0123  it is a ball
    1434  mirror
    0234  chain saw
   01312  radiator
```

I need to do a postgres `\copy` operation to a table called mytable. I used

```
\COPY mytable FROM '/home/myuser/Documents/tbfile.csv' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;
```

I defined this table as

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   code text,
   description text
);
```

I noticed that the table became

```
     code  description
    ----  ----------------
    11     it is a car
    123    it is a ball
    1434   mirror
    234    chain saw
   1312    radiator
```

i.e. the 0s were 'eliminated'. How can I do to avoid this problem and keep those 0s?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you define that column dtype as string and use `str.zfill(4)`?

Comment: not all codes are of length 4